# use php to display log in and log out link according to active session

Tags: php, html, authentication, logout

This is the code i have at the moment but will not work, displays log out button when logged in only on one page then logs user out automatically ?

```
<?php
if(!session_is_registered(myusername))

{
echo '<a href="login.php"><b>Log In</b></a>';
}

else 
{
echo  '<a href="log_out.php"><b>Log Out</b></a>';
}


?>
```

Comment: [`session_is_registered()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-is-registered.php) is deprecated, you forgot quotes around `myusername` and you don't seem to start your session.

Comment: Is `myusername` a constant, or did you just forget quotes/`$`?

Answer (score 3):

You had forgotten to do `session_start()` out of many things, and please make sure to share that, on every one of your pages, where you want to enable session protection.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && empty($_SESSION['username']))

{
echo '<a href="login.php"><b>Log In</b></a>';
}

else 
{
echo  '<a href="log_out.php"><b>Log Out</b></a>';
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`session_is_registered` is deprecated. Try using `$_SESSION` instead

```
if ($_SESSION["isLoggedIn"]) {
    // Log out HTML goes here
} else {
    // Log in HTML goes here
}
```

You'll need to include `session_start()` at the top of all of your files and you can set `$_SESSION["isLoggedIn"]` just like any other variable: `$_SESSION["isLoggedIn"] = TRUE`